# Apply linear stretch to Landsat 8 images in the tmap R package

Tags: raster, r, landsat-8, tmap

I have a Landsat 8 dataset downloaded from the USGS. I import into R using the following code:

```
B1 <- raster("LC08_L2SP_166072_20210819_20210827_02_T1_SR_B1.TIF")
B2 <- raster("LC08_L2SP_166072_20210819_20210827_02_T1_SR_B2.TIF")
B3 <- raster("LC08_L2SP_166072_20210819_20210827_02_T1_SR_B3.TIF")
B4 <- raster("LC08_L2SP_166072_20210819_20210827_02_T1_SR_B4.TIF")
B5 <- raster("LC08_L2SP_166072_20210819_20210827_02_T1_SR_B5.TIF")
B6 <- raster("LC08_L2SP_166072_20210819_20210827_02_T1_SR_B6.TIF")
B7 <- raster("LC08_L2SP_166072_20210819_20210827_02_T1_SR_B7.TIF")

fcc_nir <- stack(B5, B4, B3)

summary(fcc_nir)

summary(fcc_nir)
        LC08_L2SP_166072_20210819_20210827_02_T1_SR_B5 LC08_L2SP_166072_20210819_20210827_02_T1_SR_B4
Min.                                              6940                                           6968
1st Qu.                                          14457                                           8718
Median                                           15245                                           9237
3rd Qu.                                          15919                                           9733
Max.                                             23358                                          18272
NA's                                          17617575                                       17617575
        LC08_L2SP_166072_20210819_20210827_02_T1_SR_B3
Min.                                              7359
1st Qu.                                           8899
Median                                            9174
3rd Qu.                                           9469
Max.                                             16525
NA's                                          17617575
Warning message:
In .local(object, ...) :
  summary is an estimate based on a sample of 1e+05 cells (0.17% of all cells)
```

The images are 16bit. I can plot the false-colour composite image quite easily using this command:

```
plotRGB(fcc_nir, stretch = "lin")
```

[image]

However, I need to overlay polygons and add a map grid etc. The tmap package makes great maps but I still have to figure out how to apply the same linear stretch in tmap. When I plot the false-colour composite image, it appears dark:

```
tm_shape(fcc_nir) +
  tm_rgb(max.value = max(maxValue(fcc_nir)))
```

[image]

Do I need to rescale the image manually beforehand?

It would be nice if `tm_rgb()` had a stretch parameter like `plotRGB()`.

Comment: What does `summary(fcc_nir)` say? What's the range of values in each raster layer?

Comment: I added summary info as requested.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to improve the contrast:

```
fcc_nir_s <- terra::stretch(fcc_nir, minv = 0, maxv = 255, minq = 0.2, maxq = 0.98)

tm_shape(fcc_nir_s) +
  tm_rgb()
```

This rescales rasters to 8-bit and stretches histogram between 2nd and 98th percentile value.

[image: stretch_1]

Adjusting to 1st and 99th percentile produces this:

```
fcc_nir_s <- terra::stretch(fcc_nir, minv = 0, maxv = 255, minq = 0.1, maxq = 0.99)

tm_shape(fcc_nir_s) +
  tm_rgb()
```

[image: stretch_2]

Answer (score 0):

Linear stretch with `stretch="lin"` in `plotRGB` will stretch up to the max of your data, which is 23358. If you do:

```
tmap(fcc_nir) +
  tm_rgb(max.value = max(values(fcc_nir)))
```

then you should get the same scaling as `plotRGB(..., stretch="lin")`.

I think the `max.value` parameter to `tm_rgb` is like the `scale` parameter to `plotRGB`:

```
max.value: for ‘tm_rgb’, what is the maximum value per layer? By
          default 255.

   scale: integer. Maximum (possible) value in the three channels.
          Defaults to 255 or to the maximum value of ‘x’ if that is
          known and larger than 255
```

Comment: I tried this potentially neat solution but max value = NA. Yet when I use ```PlotRGB()``` it plots!

Comment: If I use ```maxValue(fcc_nir )``` or ```print(fcc_nir)``` get the maximum value = 65535. When I do ```summary(fcc_nir)``` it shows the 23358 value. I plugged in ```tm_rgb(max.value = 23358``` and this produced a much lighter image but not as contrasty as ```plotRGB(fcc_nir, stretch = "lin")```

Comment: I tried ```tm_rgb(max.value = max(cellStats(fcc_nir, "max")))``` and that works. The max value is higher than 23358, so the image is still on the dark side.

Comment: If I use ```fcc_nir <- setMinMax(fcc_nir)``` then ```tm_rgb(max.value = max(maxValue(fcc_nir)))``` works as well. However, the max value is a lot more than what ```summary(fcc_nir)``` reports.

Comment: ```summary(fcc_nir)``` is sampling a fraction of the cells. No wonder it reports a lower max value ....

Comment: Could you edit your question to show what your plot looks like with all these different functions and options, and which one you are trying to make with `tmap`? I created a simple 10x10x3 RGB raster for testing that had similar summary properties to yours, but very large rasters do get sampled which means scaling can be stochastic depending on if the sampling hit a rare large value or not.

Comment: Added images as requested.

Comment: I suspect ```plotRGB()``` produces a brighter and more contrasty output because it uses highly sampled data. I will put in a tmap feature request for a stretch parameter.

Comment: `maxValue` will take its value from the on-disk metadata for an on-disk raster to save scanning large rasters, and this returns 65535 as the largest *possible* value for a 16 bit raster. Use eg `B3 = setMinMax(B3)` to recompute the min max by scanning all the raster values.

Comment: `plotRGB` with `stretch` may be stretching between min and max values, whereas `tm_rgb` with `max.value` is stretching between *zero* and max value, resulting in slightly more contrast with `plotRGB` because of the min value is > 0.

Comment: I agree. There is no ```min.value =``` option in ```tm_rgb()```.